# Is there a simple way to handle SECRET_KEY update for encrypted fields?

Tags: python, django, security, encryption

Let's begin with two assumptions:

1. Some of database fields like third party access tokens are encrypted using e.g. Fernet and `SECRET_KEY` as encryption key.
2. `SECRET_KEY` needs to be changed, because of security problem.

What would be the best thing to do in such situation? I assume that I should change the `SECRET_KEY` immediately after I've fixed the security hole, however if I do that I'll essentially lose access to all of the encrypted data.

What I have came up with is to first do a migration, which would temporarily replace encrypted fields with simple charfields/textfields + data migration to unencrypt stored values. Then change the `SECRET_KEY`. Finally bring the encrypted fields back, again with a data migration to encrypt stored values.

It seems like a great hassle though, is there a better/simpler/faster way to handle such situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have one secret key, your only resort is to re-encrypt the entire database.

The proper way is to first not use django's `SECRET_KEY` for database tasks (even django doesn't use it for things like user passwords) and implement a key-rotation algorithm for your sensitive data.

[`django-fernet-fields`](https://django-fernet-fields.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#keys) provides this function out of the box; however it assumes you are rotating keys as best practice and not as consequence of a compromise.

Best-practice key rotation relies on "encryption at use" where a secret is unencrypted with the old key and re-encrypted with the new key upon use.  Eventually your most used secrets are re-encrypted and you can do an audit to invalidate or force the re-encryption of the remaining entries.